# Centralizar texto no header

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, pessoal. Criei um header com 100% do tamanho de tela (independente do tamanho de tela) assim:

```css
header {
  background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="texto-header">
    <h1>Nova Zelândia</h1>
    <p>Um paraiso do outro lado do mundo.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Preciso que meu texto fique no centro desse header (horizontal e vertical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `transform: translateY()` para centralizar verticalmente e `text-align: center` para centralizar horizontalmente:

```css
header{
   background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: yellow;
 }

.texto-header{
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="texto-header">
    <h1>Nova Zelândia</h1>
    <p>Um paraiso do outro lado do mundo.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Cara, algo não deu certo. O texto ficou no meio da página, mas não ficou exatamente no meio, sabe? Ele ficou meio alinhada a esquerdo.

Comment: Fiz uma pequena alteração, veja agora.

Comment: Agora funcionou. Acredito que um menu que eu tinha feito aqui tambem atrapalhou, hehe. Muito obrigado, =).

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto abaixo, utilizei o `display:flex` e suas *propriedades* na classe `texto-header`:

```css
header {
  background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.texto-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;  
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="texto-header">
    <h1>Nova Zelândia</h1>
    <p>Um paraiso do outro lado do mundo.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Cara, não funcionou. O texto ficou centralizado horizontalmente, mas não ficou verticalmente.